# Strange behavior of Tumblr when adding JS

Tags: javascript, tumblr

first of all I'm kinda new to JavaScript. However I wrote a tiny script to check if the DOM is ready and then fix the header of my tumblr blog when the page is scrolled.

My code looks like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
console.log("DOM ready!");

function fixHeader() {
  var header = document.querySelector("#js--site-header");
  var offset = 100;
  // only used to see the current offset when debugging
  console.log(window.scrollY);

  window.scrollY >= offset 
      ? header.classList.add("js--header-fixed") 
      : header.classList.remove("js--header-fixed");
 };

document.addEventListener("scroll", fixHeader);
});
```

I simulated the exact same code on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/kevingimbel/details/fozKh) to test if it's a bug inside my code or a problem with Tumblr. By now it seems like Tumblr is the problem.
Whenever I scroll the page over 100px it reloads instead of fixing the header to the top. On CodePen everything works as expected and the header get's fixed.

You can see my blog with the not-working code from above [here](http://atarijunge.de) (NSFW)

Every help or hint would be appreciated, I've no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: there could be a JS exception happening but because the page is reloading you are losing it. depending on which console you are using (Frirebug?) there will be a "Persist" type button which will leave the JS messages/exceptions in the console after the page is reloaded - have a look if you get anything there and post it up?

Comment: I'm using the Chrome build-in Console. It keeps all things that happening inside the DOM as long as the page is not manually reloaded (F5). Whenever I scroll down the page "flashes" ans jumps back to top (immediately). Here's a screenshot after scrolling down several times. (logged with console.log(window.offsetY) 53 & 106 when using the Mouse-wheel, other numbers when dragging the scrollbar fast). [Screenshot (imgur)](http://imgur.com/WGom11t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are experiencing is not a reload (you can use tools like Firebug to see whether your browser creates any HTTP requests). The problem in your tumblr blog is that the "header" you are trying to fix also contains the whole content. Thus, as soon as 100px offset is reached, the whole content is fixed and no scrollable content is left. The scroll offset falls back to 0, your event handler is triggered a second time and the event handler un-fixes the "header" again.

Move your `</header>` in front of `<main class="content">`.

Comment: FML. How embarrassing I didn't saw the header wasn't closed. Thanks, you saved me a lot of time. I have no idea how long it would have taken me to see this.